# Cannot handle OpenDirect push notification when iOS app is not launched

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, ios, notification, mobilepush-ios

Thank you for creating versatile push notification solution and recent update of SDK v8 was much Swifty API

I have a problem handling OpenDirect push notifications when the app is not launched.

I read [Enable Push](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-configureforpush.html) and follow implementation but `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate.userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` not called when open push notification in app not launched.

Problem was setting `SFMCSdk.mp.setURLHandlingDelegate(self)` and `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in completion handler called after application did finish launch, because `SFMCSdk.initializeSdk(ConfigBuilder().setPush(config: mobilePushConfiguration, onCompletion: completionHandler).build())`'s completionHandler call in async.

Apple document says you need to set `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` before your app finishes launching.

[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate)

> You must assign your delegate object to the UNUserNotificationCenter object before your app finishes launching. For example, in an iOS app, you must assign it in the application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) or application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method of your app delegate. Assigning a delegate after the system calls these methods might cause you to miss incoming notifications.

Also, I tried to implement `AppDelegate.application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` followed by your document, but MarketingCloud SDK logged `Module  is not initialized. You need to initialize before using. Current status: initializing.

> / MobilePush SDK: REQUIRED IMPLEMENTATION
> ** This delegate method offers an opportunity for applications with the "remote-notification" background mode to fetch appropriate new data in response to an incoming remote notification. You should call the fetchCompletionHandler as soon as you're finished performing that operation, so the system can accurately estimate its power and data cost.
> This method will be invoked even if the application was launched or resumed because of the remote notification. The respective delegate methods will be invoked first. Note that this behavior is in contrast to application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:, which is not called in those cases, and which will not be invoked if this method is implemented. **/
> unc application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
> SFMCSdk.mp.setNotificationUserInfo(userInfo)
> completionHandler(.newData)

##### Enviroment

MarketingCloud SDK v8.0.6
iOS 15.5

Is there something I missed?

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SFMCSdk.mp.setURLHandlingDelegate(self) should be set only after successful initialization of the SDK.

For opendirect, when app is not in launched state, the SDK instance will be lost and hence when you launch the app the SDK starts initializing again along with the other application lifecycle events and hence SDK get  into "Initializing" state.

Hence, The notification object should be held in the application in memory variable when the app is launched through remote notification and set it to the marketingCloudSDK after the SDK's operational status is "Operational" using SDK's  method below:

```
SFMCSdk.mp.setNotificationRequest(notificationRequest).
```

**Note**: If in SceneDelegate, may have to handle it in below function as

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
     if let response = connectionOptions.notificationResponse {
                   
        self.notificationRequest = response.notification.request
       }
 }
```

if in Appdelegate, should be handled in

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool 
{
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Prakashini

Comment: Thank you for descriptive explanation

So, handling incoming notifications needs to store notification objects in variable before SDK goes ‘operational’ status and then pass notification objects to SDK when status changes to ‘operational’.
And after ‘operational’ status handling new incoming notifications never need that kind of workaround.

I think every SDK user needs the same facility to handle notification when initializing SDK.

I hope this kind of use case will be handled in future SDK releases without a workaround.

Thank you for your kindly support